# React: Class Based Context API to Hook Based context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am really new in Hooks and during learning faces many difficulties to switch from the old style.

My old code looks like:

`context.js`

```
import React from "react";

const SomeContext = React.createContext(null);

export const withContext = (Component) => (props) => (
  <SomeContext.Consumer>
    {(server) => <Component {...props} server={server} />}
  </SomeContext.Consumer>
);

export default SomeContext;
```

`main index.js`

```
<SomeContext.Provider value={new SomeClass()}>
   <App />
</SomeContext.Provider>
```

but when I want to access it through with `export default withContext(SomeComponent)` by `this.props.server.someFunc()` it showed props is undefined in the classless hook function.

how can I achieve `this.props` in react hook

Edit:

SomeClass is not React inheriting class and its look like it.

```
class SomeClass {
  someFunc = (id) => axios('api endpoints')
}
```

SomeComponent

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
...

useEffect(() => {
   this.props.server.someFunc(id).then(...).catch(...)
}, ...)

...
}
```

Comment: It should be `value={<SomeClass/>}`, and you better *show* us the code instead of describing what you trying to do. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: SomeClass is a simple Class without inheriting react.

Comment: Just show the code... You don't have `this.props` in function components.

Comment: Okay I edit main post

Comment: Please take a look in React docs, that's not how you use Context, see useContext

Comment: I don't know how to use ```use context``` in this scenario. I am little bit confusing to calling props within ```useContext```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the regular case, you need to export the Context, then import it and use it within `useContext`:

```
export const SomeContext = React.createContext(null);


// Usage
import { SomeContext } from '..';

const SomeComponent = () => {
  const server = useContext(SomeContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    server.someFunc(id);
  });
};
```

But in your case, since you using HOC, you have the `server` within the `prop` it self:

```
const SomeComponent = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.server.someFunc(id);
  });
};
```